# How to integrate all the plot menus (file, edit, insert, etc) in a matlab GUI?

Tags: user-interface, matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am building a matlab GUI interface for data analysis. 
I have an axes object on it and I would like to add the same menus that are available in a `plot` figure.

I know you can build your own menu entries but I just need the "standard" ones i.e. *File*, *Edit*, *View*, *Insert*,  etc.

Having just the *toolbar* is not enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
 set(hf, 'MenuBar','figure')
```

Answer (score 1):

If `hf` is the handle of your GUI figure, then try:

```
set(hf, 'ToolBar', 'auto')
```

or

```
set(hf, 'ToolBar', 'figure')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but with the second line, I get the toolbar but not the menus :(